# Pakistani Passport: Missing entry stamp into Germany

Tags: passports, germany, passport-stamps

I arrived in Germany in September on a **student visa**. I got the exit stamp from Pakistan but the immigration officer at Munich airport did not put an '***Entry***' stamp on my passport. I did not notice at that time as I was tired and in a hurry. But now I am bit worried.

Will this cause any issue? And how can I sort this issue

Comment: Do you have a German study visa valid longer than 3 months? If so, the requirement is that you leave before the last date on your visa. There's no need to stamp your passport to show compliance with the Schengen 90/180 rule because it doesn't apply so they don't bother.

Comment: @CannonFodder Thanks for the quick reply and Yes my study visa is currently valid for 6 months. I will apply for a visa extension in the last month as I am in Germany for a 2 years master degree. So no need to worry?

Comment: You should ask how long the extension request usually takes in your region. One month may be too short. The students' council (ASTA) in your university might know.

Comment: You're meant to apply for a residence permit as soon as you arrive in Germany, and before your D visa expires. Your university can help you with this, or you can ask questions about the residence permit on our sister site [expatriates.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Schengen rules, the German border guard *should* have stamped your passport when you arrived, irrespective of you having a long-stay visa. But the consequences for you of not having the stamp are small or nonexistent.

In general the Schengen system depends on entry/exit stamps for documenting how long a traveler has been in the Area, and verifying that he complies with the 90/180 day rule. (There is not currently a common database of entrances and exits that can replace this). However, in your case since you have a long-stay visa, the stamps can't be used for that purpose anyway, since days you spend in Germany under the visa are exempt from the 90-day count. And you *never* get stamps while traveling *between* the Schengen countries, so enforcing the 90/180 rule for foreigners with long-stay visas is up to the honor system and extrinsic evidence anyway.

As Aganju says, you might be able to reduce practical troubles by holding on to boarding passes or other documentation for when you traveled. Most likely this documentation will never even be demanded of you, though, since your current status is in effect independently of when you arrived in the Schengen area.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about the missing stamp; many countries don't use the stamping for their records anymore anyway.

Your visa defines when you need to leave (unless you get an extension), and nobody will care when exactly you arrived, assuming that whenever it was, it was verified and you were admitted.
If it makes you feel better, keep the boarding pass from your flight, and the respective emails with the booking confirmation. With that information, the airline can always verify as needed that they flew you in that day.